# Displaying Home header on other Tab screens after adding authentication.(Following React Navigation Docs)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-navigation

Hope you have a great day~

With help of @Wen W, I managed to show one Home header on Home screen. But now I have Home header on other Tabs screens as shown. What should I change to display each screen's own header?

[Home Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mmLMG.jpg)
[History Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uUgvI.jpg)

The code is

```
const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

function HomeTabs() {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator>
      <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
      <Tab.Screen name="History" component={HistoryScreen} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Request" component={RequestScreen} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Account" component={AccountScreen} />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
}

const BottomStack = createStackNavigator();

function HomeStack() {
  return (
    <BottomStack.Navigator>
      <BottomStack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeTabs} />
      <BottomStack.Screen name="ShiftConfirmation" component={ShiftConfirmation} />
      <BottomStack.Screen name="ShiftConfirmed" component={ShiftConfirmed} />
      <BottomStack.Screen name="RequestConfirmation" component={RequestConfirmation} />
      <BottomStack.Screen name="RequestConfirmed" component={RequestConfirmed} />
    </BottomStack.Navigator>
  );
}
```

...

```
  return (
    <SafeAreaProvider>
      <AuthContext.Provider value={authContext}>
        <NavigationContainer>
          <Stack.Navigator>
            {state.isLoading ? (
              // We haven't finished checking for the token yet
              <Stack.Screen name="Splash" component={SplashScreen} />
            ) : state.userToken == null ? (
              // No token found, user isn't signed in
              <Stack.Screen
                name="SignIn"
                component={SignInScreen}
                options={{
                  title: 'Sign in',
              // When logging out, a pop animation feels intuitive
                  animationTypeForReplace: state.isSignout ? 'pop' : 'push',
                }}
              />
            ) : (
              // User is signed in
              <Stack.Screen options={{ headerShown: false }} name="SignedIn" component={HomeStack} />
            )}
          </Stack.Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>
      </AuthContext.Provider>
    </SafeAreaProvider>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

because you have two stack screens with the name `Home`. you can remove the header from one of them.

```
) : (
              // User is signed in
              <Stack.Screen options={{headerShown: false}} name="Home" component={HomeTabs} />
            )}
          </Stack.Navigator>
```

....

```
  <BottomStack.Screen options={{headerShown: false}} name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
```

...

Comment: Thanks Wen  but I still can see the header after adding the option. Actually I see the Home header on every screen, rather than each screen's header.

Comment: you have two stacks screen with the same name, so just added the same option to the other Home screen. see edited answer.